# How make a field in an Entity be built from two columns?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a table with the columns `IsActive` and `CanBeUsed` (don't ask why, it's not my choice). I want my entity to have one field called `isWorkable` that is done from those two fields. How can i do this?

The only thing I can think of is to do:

```
[Table(Name = "Task")]
public class Task
{
    ...elided...

    private string IsActive;

    [Column(Storage = "IsActive")]
    public string activeState
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IsActive;
        }

        set
        {
            this.IsActive = value;
        }
    }

    private string CanBeUsed;

    [Column(Storage = "CanBeUsed")]
    public string useState
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CanBeUsed;
        }

        set
        {
            this.CanBeUsed = value;
        }
    }

    private bool isWorkable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.IsActive == "Y" && this.CanBeUsed == "Y";
        }
    }
}
```

But I would prefer that the two fields from the DB either are private (no public getter/setter) or don't exist and I can somehow make a custom setter that maps to two columns for `isWorkable`.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can map private properties like this:https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/26/code-first-data-annotations-on-non-public-properties/

Comment: There is probably a better way to do this but just off the top of my head: Could you implement a viewModel wrapper on top of your model that contains your extra field then have it implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to detect changes on the other two fields in order to set your new value of workable. Like I said, just kinda thinking out loud so making this a comment rather than an answer.